# Which sorting algorithm does TensorFlow use?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to figure out how TensorFlow's `sort` function works.

I've looked in the docs and tried to find in the source code without luck.

The function is `tf.contrib.framework.sort(values)`?
[1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/sort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sort source code, [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/sort_ops.py#L175) is the line where the actual sort operation is called. The topk op is actually part of the core kernels and is written in C/C++. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/topk_op.cc) is the corresponding source code for it. A quick high level glance seems to employ some form of heap sort.